# Query using analytic functions in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I have the following tables in postgresql and I would like to make a query using analytical functions to obtain the following results: The name of the athlete, the discipline and the country, A column indicating the best time of the discipline. (REGISTER_MEASURE), A column containing the average time by country and discipline, A column containing the number of participations by country and discipline, A column containing the cumulative of the previous column (we will see at the end the number of participants in the discipline), The information must be sorted by discipline, country and athlete. All in a single output.

```
CREATE TABLE olympic.tb_discipline  (
  discipline_id  INT NOT NULL,
  name           CHARACTER VARYING(50) NOT NULL,
  inventor       CHARACTER VARYING(50) NOT NULL,
  type           CHARACTER VARYING(10) NOT NULL,
  object_type    CHARACTER VARYING(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT ck_discipline_type CHECK (type IN ('RUN', 'JUMP', 'THROW')),
  CONSTRAINT pk_discipline PRIMARY KEY (discipline_id)
);

CREATE TABLE olympic.tb_athlete    (
  athlete_id    CHARACTER(7) NOT NULL,
  name          CHARACTER VARYING(50) NOT NULL,
  country       CHARACTER VARYING(3) NOT NULL,
  substitute_id  CHARACTER(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_athlete PRIMARY KEY (athlete_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_athlete_substitute FOREIGN KEY (substitute_id) REFERENCES olympic.tb_athlete (athlete_id)
);

CREATE TABLE olympic.tb_play    (
  athlete_id    CHARACTER(7) NOT NULL,
  discipline_id  INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_play PRIMARY KEY (athlete_id, discipline_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_play_athlete FOREIGN KEY (athlete_id) REFERENCES olympic.tb_athlete (athlete_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_play_discipline FOREIGN KEY (discipline_id) REFERENCES olympic.tb_discipline (discipline_id)
);

CREATE TABLE olympic.tb_round (
  round_number  INT NOT NULL,
  discipline_id INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_round PRIMARY KEY (discipline_id, round_number),
  CONSTRAINT fk_round_discipline FOREIGN KEY (discipline_id) REFERENCES olympic.tb_discipline (discipline_id)
);

CREATE TABLE olympic.tb_register (
  athlete_id    CHARACTER(7) NOT NULL,
  round_number  INT NOT NULL,
  discipline_id INT NOT NULL,
  register_date  DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
  register_position INT DEFAULT NULL,
  register_time     TIME DEFAULT NULL,
  register_measure  REAL DEFAULT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_register PRIMARY KEY (athlete_id, round_number, discipline_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_register_athlete FOREIGN KEY (athlete_id) REFERENCES olympic.tb_athlete (athlete_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_register_round FOREIGN KEY (discipline_id, round_number) REFERENCES olympic.tb_round (discipline_id, round_number)
);
```

I have tried to implement the query similar to the following but I am not getting satisfactory results.

```
SELECT tb_athlete.name, tb_discipline.name
     , tb_athlete.country
     , MAX(tb_register.register_measure) OVER (PARTITION BY tb_discipline.name)
     , AVG(tb_register.register_time) OVER (PARTITION BY tb_discipline.name)
FROM olympic.tb_athlete 
JOIN olympic.tb_register USING (athlete_id) 
JOIN olympic.tb_discipline USING (discipline_id);
```

[Image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMiye.png)

Could you help me with a solution. Thank you!

Comment: please provide sample input and output.

Comment: Hi @RahulBiswas I've edited the post and I've added the output I should get. Thnak you!